# call viewController func from model.swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to clean my `GameplayViewController` code by moving what can be moved to `CurrentData.swift`. What I had:
`GameplayViewController.swift`:

```
current = CurrentData.init(howManyRooms: rooms)

for index in 0...current!.items.count-1 {
    if current!.firstLaunch {
        createItems(imageName: current!.items[index].imageName)
    }
}
```

And it worked fine. Then I had an idea of moving the for-loop to `CurrentData.init` code:
`CurrentData.swift`:

```
init(howManyRooms: Int) {
    self.size = Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(howManyRooms))))
    
    for index in 0...items.count-1 {
        if self.firstLaunch {
            GameplayViewController.createItems(imageName: items[index].imageName)
        }
    }
}
```

And I got this error: "Instance member 'createItems' cannot be used on type 'GameplayViewController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"
Is there a worthy way to call `GameplayViewController` func from `CurrentData.swift`?
Here is the func itself:

```
 public func createItems(imageName: String) {
        let imageNamePNG = "\(imageName).png"
        let itemImage = UIImage(named: imageNamePNG)
        let itemImageView = UIImageView(image: itemImage)
        if let freeSpace = self.freeSpace {
            itemImageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: Int.random(in: Int(freeSpace.minX) ... Int(freeSpace.maxX)),
            y: Int.random(in: Int(freeSpace.minY) ... Int(freeSpace.maxY)),
            width: 63, height: 63)
        }
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
        itemImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        itemImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        view.addSubview(itemImageView)
        current?.createdImages.append(itemImageView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a UICollectionView for what you are trying to do.

You would load your images in cells and there are delegate methods available for when you tap on a cell, so you do not have to worry about setting up gestures and all that.

Also, look up the Model View Controller pattern for managing your views, data and logic in a clean way. Data should not have any dependencies on views.